# Force user to update app from Google Play Store if new version is available Android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play

I`m trying to implement **in-app-update** when user open my application and detect that in Google Play Store have newer version for update to show dialog for update.
I follow [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) and my code looks:

```
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
            try {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, 99);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that app version in Play Store is **versionCode**: 41 **versionName**:10.1 and when i try to downgrade my test version with 40 and 10.0 for testing purpose **updateAvailability()** return that no update is available and **availableVersionCode()** is 35 which confuse me alot.

**EDIT:**
On advice from @Nick Fortescue i checked Google play store for beta version - but one has never been uploaded. It`s like that there are 6 higher version after 35 and you can check here -> [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN1zF.jpg)

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem

Comment: Still searching but without any success..

Answer (score 0):

That is weird, and sounds like a bug. I recommend you contact Google Play support and report it. You can do this in the Play Console behind the help (question mark) icon. It's a fairly new feature so there could still be bugs.

Without knowing your app details I can't help more. However, I'm wondering if your app has a beta channel, and you still have version 35 published on the beta channel, and you are registered as a beta tester (or something similar). Even if this is the case, it is still a bug, but it would explain why version 35 is being displayed. You could check your other tracks, and see if you have any testing tracks with version 35 active.

Comment: It`s appears that there are no beta version upload at all, you can check my edit answer for screenshot;